# Calculating database query disk IO cost

Tags: relational-database

Hey guys I'm working on some problems in a database course and I'm confused on how to calculate costs for queries that use selects with multiple conditions, some of them equality, other range.

For example, if I have a table  `At(vehicle, place, time)` and I have the number of tuples T(At), blocks B(At), and distinct values V(At, attr) for vehicle, place and time and also whether I have an index for an attribute and whether that index clustered or not.

Say I want the disk IO cost for a query that gives vehicles at place p between times t1 and t2, so that is the selection on `σ(place=p^time>t1^time<t2)` how would I go about calculating that?

I know that for simple equality queries I could use then `B(At)/V(At, attr)` if I had a clustered index for attr or `T(At)/V(At, attr)` if I had an unclustered index.

But how do I calculate costs for queries that select on more than one attributes?